# User_segments not showing all the indexes in DB

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a DB with more than 100 DB tables and created indexes for around 30 tables among those. This is shown properly in the tables 'user_indexes' or 'dba_ind_columns', but I see only 5 indexes when I check the 'user_segments' table. Please let me know the cause of this and how to fix this.

This shows all the indexes I have in DB, approx. 30:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME 
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS;
```

This also shows all the indexes in DB:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INDEX_NAME 
FROM USER_INDEXES;
```

This show only 5 indexes in DB

```
SELECT SEGMENT_NAME 
FROM USER_SEGMENTS 
WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'INDEX';
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between the `dba_xxx` views and the `user_xxx` views?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DBA_SEGMENTS` instead of `USER_SEGMENTS` to see not only the segments in your current schema, but through all database, and include views for `PARTITIONS` and `SUBPARTITIONS` to your listings as :

```
SELECT OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_SEGMENTS 
 WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'INDEX'
 ORDER BY OWNER, SEGMENT_NAME;

SELECT INDEX_OWNER, INDEX_NAME
  FROM DBA_IND_PARTITIONS 
 GROUP BY INDEX_OWNER, INDEX_NAME 
 ORDER BY INDEX_OWNER, INDEX_NAME; 

SELECT INDEX_OWNER, INDEX_NAME
  FROM DBA_IND_SUBPARTITIONS 
 GROUP BY INDEX_OWNER, INDEX_NAME 
 ORDER BY INDEX_OWNER, INDEX_NAME;
```